# Two MySQL functions work independently but not when combined (RAND()?)

Tags: mysql

Two MySQL functions work as expected independently, but together they return random results.  Consider these two queries:

**Query 1**

This returns me the row where `id=8` obviously:

`SELECT * FROM table_categories WHERE id = 8`

**Query 2**

According to my table setup this consistently returns a number between 1 and 16:

```
SELECT cat.id FROM table_categories cat 
LEFT JOIN table_user_to_category u2c 
ON u2c.cat_id = cat.id AND u2c.user_id = 0 
ORDER BY IFNULL(u2c.count,0), RAND() LIMIT 1
```

**Combined**

Oddly enough, this sometimes returns a row from `table_categories`, sometimes returns 2 rows, sometimes 3, sometimes none. What the heck?

```
SELECT * FROM table_categories WHERE id = (
SELECT cat.id FROM table_categories cat 
LEFT JOIN table_user_to_category u2c 
ON u2c.cat_id = cat.id AND u2c.user_id = 0 
ORDER BY IFNULL(u2c.count,0), RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

Is this because of `RAND()`?  I can't figure it out!  Seems like odd behavior to me, but I'm a relative newbie.

Comment: Just some advice; if you run a query like this against a heavily read table you will bring the database to it's knees. RAND() is the anti-performant.

Comment: @MikePurcell, good advice for heavily read tables, but not my case.  It's rarely read and my subquery returns 10 or so rows. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710048/good-idea-bad-idea-using-mysql-rand-outside-of-a-small-set-of-subquery-result

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `id` is defined as a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`? Otherwise you could easily have multiple rows with the same ID, which are all being returned if the random number picks them.

Comment: Yes, `id` on `table_categories` is a PRIMARY KEY. 
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |

Comment: One other comment if this matters, is that on `table_user_to_category` `user_id` and `cat_id` have a combined unique index.

Comment: Also, not to flood this answer with comments, but even if that were the case, wouldn't it still be strange that it returns a random number of results?